# How to use Jeditable plugin with admin-ajax.php?

Tags: ajax

Jeditable is saving data to the file like:

```
$('.edit_area').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
         type      : 'textarea',
         cancel    : 'Cancel',
         submit    : 'OK',
         indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
         tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
     });`
```

How do I replace JQuery.ajax with admin-ajax.php?
Do I just replace http://www.example.com/save.php to admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?

Comment: Have you tried just replacing it? Btw: That's a snippet. You'll have to show a) your whole code and b) show what you already tried/what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry. I finded solution after posting this question. This plugin working with url like: `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>?action=youraction`

Comment: You should post that as an answer. Might be useful for later readers. You can mark it as solution in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question. This plugin works with url formatted like:

```
$('.edit_area').editable('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>?action=youraction', {
     type      : 'textarea',
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     submit    : 'OK',
     indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
     tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
     somekey   : 'somevalue'
 });`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
$('.editable').editable(function(value, settings) { 

 $.post(
    ajaxurl,
    { action: 'ajax_action',
              data: data,
              moreData: moreData
    }, function(response) 
               {

           });

      return(value);
 }, 

 { 
   submit: 'Ok',
   tooltip: 'Click to edit title',
   cancel    : 'Cancel',
   event     : "dblclick"
 });
```

where value is what has been inserted in the editable field.